# Error env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory while running Slather on Jenkins

Tags: ruby, jenkins, environment-variables, xcode9, slather

I am trying to configure slather on my Jenkins server. Everything works fine when I run slather command using Terminal, but the script seems to fail when I run it on the Jenkins server. Each time I get env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory error when I run the script on the jenkins server.

Here is the script I am running through slather

```
slather coverage -x --output-directory /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/TestApp/test-reports/ --scheme TestApp /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/TestApp/TestApp.xcodeproj
```

Here is the PATH variable I am setting while executing this shell

> $PATH:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin

Comment: Are you setting the path like `PATH=$PATH:/Users/Shared/Jenkins/.gem/ruby/2.4.0/bin` ?? You have to assign in back to PATH. Also, it is usually safer to stick your path in the front of $PATH, not at the end. Then you know the version of your file is found first before some other thing that might be in the path that you don't know about.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rob, even after setting the PATH variable the way you described, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed this issue by running the following shell command using Jenkins.

> $Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/wrappers/slather

Earlier, I was referring to

> $Home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/bin/slather

and the bin does not have ruby environment support when executed via shell script.