# pod install throws env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory on Jenkins only

Tags: ruby, macos, jenkins, cocoapods, macos-catalina

I have tried other solutions provided, none of them helped this exact scenario.

We have recently updated Jenkins machine to Catalina, then Jenkins from 2.5 to 2.222.1, then ruby from 2.3 to 2.6, reinstalled Cocoapods.

`/usr/local/bin/pod install` command fails in Jenkins CI throwing error

```
env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

Remotely logged in to machine and running same command from same job folder in Terminal - all runs good with no issues

Anyone know what might be an issue?

Answer (score 1):

This question answer game an idea
[Error env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory while running Slather on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47163349/error-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory-while-running-slathe)

This works fine

```
$HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.5/wrappers/pod install
```

Though same fix for xcpretty doesn't seem to work. But that is for another time